# which is the best high availability technique for azure vm

Tags: azure

We planned to configure the high availability for one of our azure VM. Is there any  technique other than VM snapshot or VM backup from which we can restore VM during outages very quick.

Comment: You should review what you understand to be high availability. You should be looking at availability sets, update sets, what application you are using and what failovers it supports of can perform

Comment: Your discussing disaster recovery rather than HA.  Have you restored a managed disk and tested it in the Recovery Services Vault.  It mounts the disk with iSCSI and it restores it fast.  You can also restore a snapshot and convert it to a virtual machine but again.....this is more disaster recovery.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you mean for high availability and what your RTO/RPO is.  If you are looking to protect against a failure within a single Azure region, [**Availability Sets/Zones**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/manage-availability) should be reviewed along with Update Domains and Fault Domains.

If you are looking for HA that is multi-region, you should look at Azure Site Recovery, specifically [**Azure-to-Azure ASR**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/azure-to-azure-architecture).  This will ensure your services and withstand an outage if an entire region fails (think DR scenario).  ASR though take a few minutes to spin up the VMs in the secondary regions so if your RTO needs to be near zero you should look at a hot/hot [**multi-region architecture**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/n-tier/multi-region-sql-server).